# What is wrong about this code that causes UI to hang even after using a new thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, freeze

I'm trying to write a program that reads the serial port using c# windows form application .I've just started to learn about threads and tasks and etc. so I'm just a little bit confused about it.So even after reading some documents, I still don't know why does the following code cause the UI to hang?So,what is wrong about this code?Do you have any suggestion?Thanks.

There is a richtextbox named txtRead which is supposed to show the data that are taken from the serial port after a button named btnReadBegin get clicked.The richtextbox get updated frequently as the serial port sends the datas,but the rest of the application hangs.

```
SerialPort srlPort = new 
SerialPort("COM6",9600,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One); 
delegate void mydel();
bool checkWhile = true;
private void BtnReadBegin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            srlPort.Open();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                txtRead.BeginInvoke(new mydel(ReadingSerialPortMethod));
            }).Start();
        }
        void ReadingSerialPortMethod()
        {
            while (checkWhile)
            {
                txtRead.Text += 
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(srlPort.ReadChar()));
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's because you have an infinite loop in the ui thread. Try to put the loop and the serial ReadChar in the created thread and send the result in BeginInvoke `txtRead.BeginInvoke(() => txtRead.Text += readedChar);`

Comment: I tried following code but the problem still exists:
    private void BtnReadBegin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                srlPort.Open();
            
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (checkWhile)
                    {
                        txtRead.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=> txtRead.Text += 
    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(srlPort.ReadChar()))));
                    }
                }).Start();
            }

Comment: You need to call `ReadChar` before calling BeginInvoke

Comment: @Kalten It's working.But could you please tell me why ReadChar has to be called before BeginInvoke?

Comment: Because this method is blocking the current thread. You need to think about what is running where and when. You have 2 thread, UI and a custom one. If you want to allow UI to be responsive, you need to limit its workload by moving eavy/blocking stuff in the other thread.